# htaccess DirectoryIndex breaks access to Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress installation in my directory /blog

I recently added this line to my .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex /dgroup/index.php
```

Now I can´t access anymore the blog home page, and I can´t undestand why. I even tried to manually add

```
 RewriteRule ^blog/$ blog/index.php
```

No results.

It may be noteworthy that I *can* access single posts from the blog, just the home page is broken.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

MORE DETAILS:

By I can´t access the blog home page anymore I mean that I get an error 404.

What I am trying to achieve is simply to go on dgroup/index.php as default page

Comment: "Now I can´t access anymore the blog home page" --- what does it mean?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `dgroup/index.php should be the default page`

Remove your `DirectoryIndex` line and place this rule **as the very first rule** in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` for opening `/dgroup/index.php` while visiting home page of your domain:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /dgroup/index.php [L]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much. Just curious? Why the [L] flag? It seems to work both with and without. I though it was supposed to tell that it is the last instruction, but it seems I was wrong!

Comment: `L` means `Last` and that just stops current rewrite loop injecting rules for further processing. In this case you might not see the difference but there are rules below this then `L` might affect.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially telling apache "if a resource isn't found in a directory, serve /dgroup/index.php". Your rule will apply to **any** directory.

So when you browse to `/blog/post/something`, these directories don't exist and thus apache goes "Ok, well, nothing exists here so let's serve up /dgroup/index.php

I'm a little confused at what you're trying to achieve. If you're only wanting to serve up /dgroup/index.php when someone visits /dgroup just use something like:

```
<Directory /dgroup>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

Comment: dgroup(index.php should be the default page, so when somebody goes on domainname.com shoul land there.

Comment: Actually I can access /blog/post/something, by the way. The only problem is the blog home page