# htaccess RewriteRule to create "splash page" in WordPress root folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, splash-screen

I have wordpress installed in the root directory of a domain, and need to add some dynamic splash pages to the website for visitors to land on prior to entering the site.

I've ruled out using `front-page.php` within the theme as I need to create a number of different splash pages and serve them to the visitor based on certain criteria.

Within the root folder alongside the WP install I have a file `splash.php` which dependant on certain criteria will direct to a selection of other pages - those pages should then direct the user onto WP's `index.php` in the root directory.

At first I thought a simple DirectoryIndex would do the trick but quickly realised that wouldn't work. I then moved onto the answer provided [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21567800/758231) using `RewriteRule` but its not working as I hoped. Whilst placing the following line `RewriteRule ^/?$ /splash.php [L]` in my htaccess takes me to the correct splash page, I'm unable to access WP's index.php - every other file and directory works fine.

I've tried moving the RewriteRule around but no luck - can someone point out what I'm missing?

Here's what my htaccess currently looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#RJG ENTRY
RewriteRule ^/?$ /splash.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You could still use `front-page.php` and simply let it include the appropriate splash for the current visitor?

Comment: I never thought of it from that angle... so essentially just stick a front-page.php in my child theme and have it dynamically pull the content I need. My theme uses latest posts as the front page rather than an actual static page, so how do I get from my dynamic front-page.php content to the actual blog?

Comment: I'm being dense, ignore that comment, on it already, thanks!